# Custom URL redirect to Community Page

Tags: community, force.com-sites, custom-domain

I have a custom url companyname.com. I have a community with the url mydomain.force.com. Now when I enter the custom URL in the browser, it should redirect to community login page. Is there any way to achieve this scenario.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible as standard functionality, but you have to follow these steps:

1. Setup the domain in Salesforce
2. Get the CNAME record updated in the DNS to point to the Salesforce Org URL for the community
3. Create a Certificate Signing Request in Salesforce for the domain and get a Certification Authority to issue a certificate
4. Upload the certificate in Salesforce
5. Setup the Custom URL for the community using the domain

See SF documentation [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212707&type=1)

These cannot be made active in a sandbox environment, but can be setup in a sandbox and deployed. Therefore the sandbox URL will always be including a force.com domain.

Comment: Thanks @DaveHumm....Your answer guided me to the best route possible....I have a small doubt here...
I have gone through the link that you've provided above...So here in [domain].[18 character orgId].live.siteforce.com, under [domain], do i need to provide link of my org domain(mydomain.force.com) or Community domain(partnerdomain.com)? Please suggest

Comment: And Can we perform this in QA?
I have read somewhere that this can only be done in Prod..But before deploying to Prod, we need to test this in QA...Please suggest

Comment: It can't be activated in a Sandbox environment, and I have had to do this directly into production a number of times.